# How to setup a playlist in jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, drm

I'm trying to setup jwplayer with DRM. I want to use `playlist[].sources[]` for this.

My code looks like this:

```js
jwplayer.setup({
  playlist: [{
    sources: [
      { file: 'myfile1...' },
      { file: 'myfile2...' },
    ]
  }]
});
```

But I have this error: `Cannot add property default, object is not extensible`.
If I remove sources and just go with a file, I have no error:

```js
jwplayer.setup({
  playlist: [{
    file: 'myfile1...',
  }]
});
```

But then, I can't setup multiple version of my file to handle DRM.
What can I do?

Comment: @Yogi the code matches the docs, but it does not work anyway. What is weird is that the error is not handled well, it's a javascript error, not an error created by the lib. It seems like a bug in the lib, but I can't find where it is :(

Comment: _"I can't setup multiple version of my file to handle DRM."_ - why would you need to do that in the first place? Their example for using the player with DRM, explicitly specifies which DRM implementation to use for each source, https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/reference/playlists#sources-with-drm Are you trying to provide the _same_ content, but with _different_ DRM implementations here, or why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I want to provide the same content with different DRM implementations. But even without any drm, I'm still having the error. It seems to come from here: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/blob/30353cd1e1f3017a96ef2854ef758fb4f479cd7a/src/js/playlist/item.js#L52, but I don't know how to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue.
The code is actually somthing like this:

```js
const sources = [...];

// ...

jwplayer.setup({
  playlist: [{
    sources,
  }]
});
```

Making a copy resolve the bug:

```js
const sources = [...];

// ...

jwplayer.setup({
  playlist: [{
    sources: sources.map(source => ({ ...source })),
  }]
});
```

jwplayer will mutate object to add a `default` prop, so if your sources are memoized or an immutable object in some way, it will break.